# Can I write a script to tell me which files are currently being edited in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm using `tmux` with many windows, and I frequently lose track of which files I'm editing in vim. I'd like to have another shell open that runs a script that tells me the paths of files that vim is currently editing.

I'm running Mac OS.

Comment: Would searching for all the swap files work?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis this idea would work really well if you stuck all the swap files in a common folder (`:set directory`). Only problem is when vim crashes the files would still be there even though its not technically open.

Comment: What about revising your workflow instead and be a little more focused? Like using one vim instance and one tmux window per project, opening files from vim... Adding a hack to that mess will only make it more messy.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would tackle the problem is to query all remote Vim processes for their opened buffers. You can use Vim's *clientserver* functionality for that. The GVIM server names are usually sequentially named: `GVIM`, `GVIM1`, ...; for terminal Vim, you'd have to name them with the `--servername` argument (e.g. via a shell alias).

You can then query the list of open files via the `--remote-expr` argument. A simple expression to loop over all listed buffers (like what the `:ls` command shows) is:

```
map(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val) && ! empty(bufname(v:val))'), 'bufname(v:val)')
```

As you can see, it's a bit involved and might affect your workflow of launching Vim. Think hard whether you really need this!

Comment: btw, you can list the server names using the `--serverlist` argument.

Answer (score 0):

That I know of there is no way to get every open vim buffer from an external process.  Instead of using separate tmux layouts and a separate instance of `vim` to edit multiple files, you could have one instance of vim and edit multiple separate files using `:split` and `:tabnew`.  Then in that vim instance you can use `:ls` to see the paths of all open files relative to the current working directory.  `:pwd` also works.

If this isn't your style and you'd still like to use `vim` in separate layouts, you can use `ps` to see the arguments to each `vim` process and check the cwd of these processes.  Something like:

```
paste <(pgrep vim | xargs pwdx) <(pgrep vim | xargs ps -o %a | sed 1d)
```

Note that if you use multiple buffers in vim the above won't quite work because it will only list the arguments given to each `vim` command and not list the actual buffers.

Comment: `pwdx` doesn't exist on mac and `pgrep vim | xargs ps -o %a` gives `%a keyword not found` What's the `%a` for?

Comment: `%a` is for arguments.  You don't necessarily need it but it simplifies the output.  I'm sure you could get pwdx, but someone made: https://gist.github.com/tobym/648188

Comment: Do you know of a simple way to make the command produce new output when a vim file is closed or opened?

Comment: @RosePerrone you mean from within `vim`?

Comment: @RosePerrone if you exit vim and then use `vim file` then running the command again will show the different output

Answer (score 0):

You could tweak around with the piped commands `ps -eF | grep vim` for your script.
At the end of each line, of the result, you'll see you the different processes dealing with anything related to 'vim'. Therefore you'll find which files are currently being edited by vim('vim foo.txt' for instance), as well as 'grep vim' that was being active to get this result. To have a pretty output, you'd have to filter all of these with a script.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: This won't tell you anything if you use `:e` in vim